# Get the position of matches in Lucene

Tags: lucene

Is it possible to find the position of words with a match when the indexed field isn't stored?

### for example:

```
Query: "fox over dog"

Indexed text of matched doc: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

What I want: [4,6,9]
```

**Note1**: I know text can be highlighted using Lucene but I want the position of the words

**Note2**: The field isn't set to be stored by Lucene**

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this for practical purposes - just to give a pseudo code and pointers that you can experiment with to reach to correct solution.

Also, you have not specified your Lucene version, I am using Lucene 6.0.0 with Java.

1.While Indexing, set these two booleans for your specific field for which positions are desired. Lucene will be able to give that data if indexing has stored that information otherwise not.

```
FieldType txtFieldType = new FieldType(
            TextField.TYPE_NOT_STORED);

txtFieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true);

txtFieldType.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
```

2.At your searcher, you need to use `Terms` , `TermsEnum` & `PostingsEnum` like below,

```
`Terms terms = searcher.getIndexReader().getTermVector(hit.doc, "TEXT_FIELD");`


            if(terms.hasPositions()){
                TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator();
                PostingsEnum postings = null;
                while(termsEnum.next() != null){
                    postings  = termsEnum.postings(postings ,PostingsEnum.ALL);
                    while(postings.nextDoc() != PostingsEnum.NO_MORE_DOCS){
                        System.out.println(postings.nextPosition());
                    }
```

You need to do some of your own analysis to arrive at the data that you need but your first need to save meta data as pointed in point # 1.

```
                }
            }
```

`searcher` is IndexSearcher instance, `hit.doc` is doc id and hit is a `ScoreDoc` .